# Explanation for convoluted generic-type declaration. What does Class<? extends Class<? extends Actor>[]> actually mean?

Tags: java, class, generics, types

Imagine that we have this class.

```
public class Actor {...}
```

And then we have a method that needs a parameter that is a type of:

`Class<? extends Class<? extends Actor>[]>`

Is this even possible? I could not decipher it.

Comment: Could be wrong, but don't think you can extend a Class <...>[ ] since array is not really a class.

Comment: You are refering to `java.lang.Class` of course, don't you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Let's work from the inside out:

- `? extends Actor` means something that is `Actor` or any subtypes of `Actor`.
- `Class<? extends Actor>[]` means an array of `Class<T>` objects where each object represents a class that is either `Actor` or is a subtype of `Actor`.
- `Class<? extends Class<? extends Actor>[]>` represents **the class of an array of class objects**, where each object is either `Actor` or one of its subtypes.<sup>*</sup>

Here's an example that should make it a bit more clear:

```
//actorClass is a Class<T> object that represents Actor.class 
//or any of its subtypes
Class<? extends Actor> actorClass = Actor.class;

//classArray is an array of Class<? extends Actor> objects, and so its type is 
//Class<? extends Actor>[]
//You will get a warning about an unsafe cast here because you
//cannot really create an array of generic type, which means the
//RHS type is just `Class[]`.
Class<? extends Actor>[] classArray = new Class[] {
    actorClass, actorClass, actorClass
}; 

//Now we get the class of the array itself, which matches the convoluted
//expression you saw.
Class<? extends Class<? extends Actor>[]> classArrayClass = classArray.getClass();
```

The important thing to note here is that this giant expression **does not represent a class** that itself extends an array of `Class<? extends Actor>` objects. Instead, **it represents the class of an array** of `Class<? extends Actor>` objects.

<sup>*</sup> Technically, [you can't create an array of a generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays), which means that `Class<? extends Actor>[]` really is just `Class[]`. So eventually you just end up with `Class<Class[]>`, which is the class that represents an array of `Class` objects (i.e., just `Class[].class`).

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. Let's give this type a shorter name "CCA"

```
CCA = Class<? extends Class<? extends Actor>[]>
```

expanding the first wildcard,

```
CCA = all Class<T> where T <: Class<? extends Actor>[]
```

for array subtyping, we must have

```
T = A[] where A <: Class<? extends Actor>
```

Therefore

```
CCA = all Class<A[]> where A <: Class<? extends Actor>
```

If we explore the fact that `Class` is `final`, then A must be

```
A = Class<C> or Class<? extends C> where C <: Actor
```

Therefore

```
CCA = all Class<Class<C>[]> and  Class<Class<? extends C>[]> where C<:Actor
```

Meaning, CCA covers class objects representing arrays like `Class<Actor>[]`, `Class<BadActor>[]`,
`Class<? extends BadActor>[]` etc.

*On the other hand* ... we know that `T` cannot be arbitrary type in `Class<T>`. Though syntactically `Class<List<String>>` is valid, there is really no class for `List<String>`; there is only class `List`; therefore only `Class<List>` makes sense.

And... for arrays, even though there are compile-time types like `List<String>[]`, `List<Integer>[]`, there is only one runtime class, corresponding to `List[]`.

Therefore, CCA is really just `Class<Class[]>`; there is exactly one object for this type - `Class[].class`, i.e. the class representing the array type `Class[]`.

Given an object of type CCA, there is nothing interesting you can do with it. I'm curious to know  where did you see this type, and what's the actual use case.